# What is the best way to asbtract a Friendship user relationship in OOP?

Tags: oop

I'm modeling a solution that have a class User wich obviously represents a user in the system and i need to know what is the best way to manipulate a friendship relationship operations (add, remove, check, block) between users on my system: create a class that represents these relationships (e.g: class Friendship), or use the User class to manipulate those operations (e.g: User->add_as_friend(User $user) ).

I dont know if i was that much clear but...

Additionaly, i dont need the solution for the database side because this i already have. I just need to know how to correct represent it in a OOP perspective.

Comment: Sounds like both your options presented technically fall under oop design. What's correct may be more in what works best for you from an organizational standpoint. I would add it to the user class unless there was extensive functionality in the friendship classes that would unnecessarily bloat the user class (statistical details, etc)

Comment: I would design it so the relationship concepts are separate from those involved in the relationship. In other words, `User`s should know nothing about friendships. A `Friendship` should know about `User`s, but not the other way around. At least, when considering a `User` at its most basic level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track w/abstracting out the various relationships and behaviors.

Look into the "Strategy" and "Decorator" Design Patterns, where you encapsulate code that varies into abstract classes and protocols. This allows objects to be dynamically composed to adopt the behavior/characteristics they need to have at run time.

If you make all behavior & properties part of the "User" class, adding new features quickly becomes unwieldy and a pain to manage.

For example, let's say you decide to have different sub-classes of "User" (Admin, Kid, Adult). 
If they all inherit from a "User" base class, then the base functions would be the same.

But "askToPlay()" or "slumberParty()" would have *completely* different implementations for Kids vs Adults ... Kids probably shouldn't inherit the "romanticPartner" property or "goBarHopping()" method at all.

You could just keep those things as part of separate subclasses, but it's hard to add/remove/change them dynamically. Also, keeping up with different implementations across multiple subclasses duplicates code/effort, and creates maintenance headaches.

Instead, consider creating protocols or abstract classes to contain those behaviors. This will allow for greater flexibility down the road, and make it easier to add new functionality you haven't thought of yet.

As for who actually handles "add, remove, block" etc, the individual User instances could still do that, but it would be because they implement the addFriend removeFriend or blockUser methods that are part of an external interface, rather than internal to their class.